# Translation using Import/Export for Site with Lot of Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I'm working on a site that has lots of custom fields added using [Types](http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) and [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

The client wants 9-10 additional languages and here's their workflow:

1. We give an export file to them (can be WP export or we can write a custom plugin for this).
2. They will pass this on to translation agency.
3. We get a file back with translated content, same format.

I have tried MultiLingual Press and Polylang but they don't seem to support this workflow. Do you know of any plugin(s) that can support this workflow? (I have read about WPML but many people report having issues with it and ACF, can give it a try though)